# How to fallback to core object stringification?

Tags: perl

A package overloads stringification operator:

```
use overload '""' => sub { ... };
```

But in some places I want to fallback to default stringification behaviour.

What should I do to such objects to get `Object=HASH(0x7693218)` string again?

```
print ${ \$obj }; # Did not help
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[overload](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?overload) provides

```
overload::StrVal($arg)
```